# org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: Cannot change strategy of configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath' after it has been resolved error

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I updated Android Studio recently after a long time and immediately had many issues with building the apps but most of them were resolved when I migrated my project to androidX.

But I am not able to fix this error for quite some time. I tried `./gradlew cleanBuildCache` this but everything with Gradle fails for this project.

Currently I am getting this message when I try to sync Gradle files.

> What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: Cannot change strategy of configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath' after it has been resolved.

When I build the project I get this error:

> Cannot change strategy of configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath' after it has been resolved.

I am not able to understand what's going wrong and where.

This is my build Gradle:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Following is my App Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-  plugin:0.11.2'
}
}

android {
signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias 'key'
        keyPassword 'password1'
        storeFile file('location')
        storePassword 'password2'
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 5
    versionName "4.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    manifestPlaceholders = [
            onesignal_app_id               : 'id',
            // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
            onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
    ]
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03'
implementation 'com.github.Pradyuman7:ChocoBar:V1.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0'
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.1'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha03'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha02'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-alpha02'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should only be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it.